# Why am I seeing a 32 request limit in IIS 7.5?

Tags: iis-7.5

Environment:

WinServer 2008R2 Standard, IIS 7.5 on  MS VM with 4 Xeon x5675 @ 3.07 GHz;

ISAPI application pool - classic mode, no managed code, 32 bit enabled. Application code is 32 bit, runs under WOW64; Maximum worker processes 1;

I ran some stress testing simulating the processing of simultaneous `POSTS` to a new application I'm deploying in this environment. I confirmed and am able to predictably reproduce throttling of  the processing of more than 32 simultaneous `POSTS`: Regardless how I configure the simulation, 40 at once, 4 groups of 10 requests, etc, the result is consistent: First 32 requests are queued up and visible in the IIS admin console worker threads viewer and are successfully processed by my application. The rest are kicked back to the client with an "HTTP 1.1.5 Error" - the requests never reach my IIS application and never show up in the worker threads viewer.

Googling around I found some references to a throttling mechanism in IIS 6 that limits to 16 simultaneous requests per processor. 32 being 16x2, I surmise I'm dealing with something similar, but I haven't been able to find any direct references to such a thing in IIS 7.5.

I'd like to find out more about this apparent throttling mechanism:

Is this normal behavior, or the result of some sort of error condition?

Can this apparent 16/32 request limit be somehow controlled and configured?

How/where in the IIS logs might I find information about requests that were kicked out. I am not very familiar with the IIS logs (I'm a programmer, not a sysAdmin) and have never configured anything special with them. I could not find any indications of kick-outs in the default log files found in C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles.

Comment: I would suggest checking your stress tester - it may be limiting the number of simultaneous connections it will open to the same server.

Comment: @Brian - That's not it. I see the requests as they go out and as explained. I'm getting **back** an error from the server when my simulator posts the kicked-back requests.  There's more too, but no need to elaborate further. Tnx.